# Annotator 2.0.0-alpha.3 not working in touch devices

Tags: annotations, annotatorjs

I am using annotator js(2.0.0-alpha.3) in my application it works well in desktop and in touch devices it is not working.

I see in documentation when we use 1.2 version we can use a touch plugin but for version 2.0.0 we dont have any plugin but we have native mobile support.

**And also in documentation I can see for 2.1 version these are the changes available**
https://github.com/openannotation/annotator/blob/master/doc/roadmap.rst
The main goals for this release, which we aim to ship by Jan 1, 2016 (with a major feature freeze on Nov 15):

- Support for selections made using the keyboard
- Support in the core for annotation on touch devices
- Support for multiple typed    selectors in annotations
- Support for components that resolve    (‘reanchor’) an annotation’s
  selectors into a form suitable for    display in the page

But I could nt see any 2.1 version in github so wanted to know whether we have updated information on the same.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use 1.2 version which is officially a stable version?  I have a similar requirement, and am curious to know what you finally went with.